# ws['A' + str(row)].value starting at the wrong row line

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to loop through an excel file and assign values from individual cells to variables.
The problem I'm running into, is that it starts from the third row in Excel and I want it to start from the first line. I'm sure it's something obvious, but I haven't been able to find a solution.
This is what the code looks like (still very rough until I get it working:

```
import openpyxl

wb_name = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Names.xlsx')
ws_name = wb_name.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
maxrow=ws_name.max_row
row = 1

while row != maxrow:
    value1=ws_name['A' + str(row)].value
    value2 = ws_name['B' + str(row)].value
    row=row+1
```

Comment: You are overwriting the values already stored in `value1` and `value2` in each iteration of the `while` loop, so you end up with just the the values of the last row. What are you trying to do or calculate?

Answer (score 0):

Please use a `for` loop to iterate through the worksheet so that you don't have to manage any counters or clunky Excel coordinate generation. Each pass through the loop will overwrite any existing assignments.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Names.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

cells = []
for row in ws:
    A, B = row[:2]
    cells.append([A.value, B.value]) # capture the first two cells
```